# How would I go about proving or disproving this statement?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How would I go about proving or disproving this statement?

$$\int_{4+a}^{2a+1} \int_{4a+b}^{2b+1} \frac{6}{ {2a}(b^3+1)^{1/4}} \, {db}\,{da}=-\int_{4+a}^{2a+1} -\int_{2b+1}^{4a+b} \frac{6}{ {2a}(b^3+1)^{1/4}} \, {db}\,{da}$$

Comment: you shoudn't use the same variables for the variable of integration and  the limits of the integral. your statement should be wrong: the inner integral is transfered correctly since $\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = F(b)-F(a) = - \int_b^a f(t) \, dt = - (F(a)-F(b))$. By the same rule the outer integral will be wrong (limits weren't interchanged there, but you added a minus anyway.)

Comment: What do you know about how integrals intract with negative signs?

Comment: I think the two are not equal because the negative inverts the limits but the other question I have is whether or not there is a relationship between the two integrals ?